# Moving Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 5 solution to new server msvcr120.dll error code: 193

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, iis-7.5, windows-server-2016

I deployed a solution built in ASP.NET MVC 5 with C# and SQL Server as database to Server "X" with a locally installed SQL Server.

I moved this already deployed to a new server "Y" through "FTP" where SQL Server is not locally installed.

Both server have the same Windows OS and IIS versions.

I am getting the following error when I try to browse the deployed solution in server "Y".

[image]

I am unable to make out the reason.

I have these questions:

- does an ASP.NET MVC 5 solution with database require local SQL Server DLLs? If yes, what are those?
- Just FTP of deployed solution is not enough for moving the solution to a new server?
- Does the solution need to be redeployed to new server using Web Deploy feature?

Error 193 is referring about 32 bit vs. 64 bit conflicts.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Though I could not find a solution, I have found some discussion on the same topic. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/03bd5dc0-1c90-4a83-84ae-63143f1a683c/getting-a-microsoftsqlservertypesdll-is-incorrectly-specified-as-a-file-error-message?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: From the discussion what I understood is, The problem occurs when Web Server and DB server are separate. I have the dlls in the bin folder but they are not able to get recognized at runtime. still problem pesists

Comment: You already asked your first question by finding that discussion. For the rest, VC runtime is a native dependency, so you cannot use your current deployment process to ship it to the production machine. It must be manually installed there by the server administrators.

Comment: What I figured out was "the DLLs" though appearing as available in the destination they were not. not sure why. I "redeployed" from Visual Studio and still got the same problem. After I "COPY & PASTED" the DLLs again into the designated folder, problem resolved. I did not experiment yet but "It is possible to "Copy & Paste" the "Final Deployed" Solution from One Web Server to Another and works fine if all the DLLs are available perfectly. This consumed my 16 hour hard work. I am wondering why VS team has been ignoring resolving CRITICAL issue that wasting Development hours.

Comment: Instead of "figuring out" such basic knowledge, you really should spend some time on what Microsoft officially says, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/deployment-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017 If you do think those are CRITICAL issues, spend enough time in advance, not afterwards.

Comment: @LexLi I believe this forum is meant for Problems and Solutions and not for "unproductive comments".

Comment: Although you posted the question, it does not automatically grant you the rights to decide what is "unproductive". You shouldn't have spent 16 hours if you went "the right way" defined by the vendor.